# NaN values with Pandas Spearman and Kendall correlations

Tags: python, pandas, scipy, statistics, correlation

I am attempting to calculate Kendall's tau for a large matrix of data stored in a Pandas dataframe. Using the corr function, with method='kendall', I am receiving NaN for a row that has only one value (repeated for the length of the array). Is there a way to resolve it? The same issue happened with Spearman's correlation as well, presumably because Python doesn't know how to rank an array that has a single repeated value, which leaves me with Pearson's correlation -- which I am hesitant to use due to its normality and linearity assumptions.

Any advice is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Pearson's correlation coefficient is not defined when an input is constant, so technically, `nan` is the correct result.

Comment: But I didn’t have that issue with Pearson — only with Kendall and Spearman.

Comment: Spearman is basically Pearson applied to the ranks.  If all the ranks are the same for one of the inputs, the Spearman coefficient should also be `nan`.

Comment: Then I don’t understand why my Pearson matrix is fine, but my Spearman has the same error column that the Tau has. Is this a Pandas / SciPy issue then?

Comment: What value is in your Pearson matrix for the constant input? What code computes that value?  The function `scipy.stats.pearsonr` in the latest version of SciPy will return `nan` if one of the inputs is constant.

Comment: Essentially zero -- at most, in absolute terms, on the order of 10^-14.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to abandon the complicated mathematics in favor of intuition. Because the NaN values arose only on arrays with constant values, it occurred to me that there is no relationship between it and the other data, so I set its Spearman and Kendall correlations to zero.